# Access VBA Update Combo Box Value (From sharepoint list)

Tags: ms-access, vba

I've been trying to figure out how to do this, but everything I've tried from google has failed.
I have a button on a form that is designed to open a report and then change the value of a combo box value. The combo box originates from a Sharepoint shared list/table.
Here's my code:

```
Private Sub btnVbaOpenContractRpt_Click()

Dim rptName As String
Dim rptName2 As String
Dim rptFilter As String
Dim rptWhere As String
Dim rptArgs As String


rptName = "Report 1"
rptName2 = "Report 2"
Me("Combo Box") = "Report Generated"

DoCmd.Close acReport, rptName, acSaveNo
DoCmd.Close acReport, rptName2, acSaveNo


DoCmd.openreport rptName2, acViewPreview, rptFilter, rptWhere, acWindowNormal, rptArgs
DoCmd.openreport rptName, acViewPreview, rptFilter, rptWhere, acWindowialogue, rptArgs
End Sub
```

When a click the button to execute the code I get the following error:
"Run Time Error 3326
This Record Set is not updateable"

Any help on this?

Comment: What line gives the error?  Have the arguments been set, filter and args?

Comment: It's the combo box line that gives the error. The report args all work just fine as I've successfully tested this code to generate the report already. Also of note: The combo box is present on the form which the button is located

Comment: Me("Combo Box") = "Report Generated", this line?  What's it meant to do?

Comment: Me("Combo Box") = "Report Generated" is the line, that is correct. And this line is designed to set a the combo box value to "Report Generated" (It has a list of about 8 options)

Comment: so what line gives the error.

Comment: Me("Combo Box") = "Report Generated"
This is the line that gives the error

Comment: i think it should be me.combobox.value="Report Generated" i dont think you can have a space in the control name.

Comment: Nope, still producing the same error. Even after I changed the control name to have no spaces

Comment: Can you get the proper name of the control.  I just guessed at Combobox

Comment: The actual control name I'm using is DealStatusBox

Comment: I'd try using the correct name then.

Comment: I feel like there's been a bit of miscommunication...The control names I used in my initial code paste were generic, but represented the formatting. I am using the correct control names, and if I wasn't it would more than likely produce a different error. I have attempted to use a control name with a space, and then I changed the control name to one without a space, and it still yielded the same error. I am currently developing a work around, but if anyone has an idea of what might be happening with this, I'd appreciate some help

Comment: @mattlore - there's no miscommunication. When you post code it's assumed it's the code you're actually using - a simple copy/paste is quicker than typing in your code manually with "generic" names designed that only you know are incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The combobox you are updating is bound to a field of the form recordsource. And this recordsource is apparently not updateable. Or can you edit bound controls on the form, and save the record?

Or you have set the form to `AllowEdits = False`.

If the recordsource can't be changed, you could update `DealStatusBox` by executing an UPDATE SQL, and then refreshing the form.

Comment: Thank's Andre! It would appear that the query I'm using for the 'DealStatusBox' is a fairly complex query so it won't allow the box to be edited, which is causing the problem to be carried over into the form. So I will use an SQL UPDATE to change it. Thank you